# Managing resolution in OpenGl

Tags: opengl, screen-resolution

I use OpenGl. I would like to create a menu-control, but for this I need a constant resolution-control. I mean that I can set the position of a button by giving a coordinate, in 1024x768. But what if my window doesn't in it. And in full screen mode I hasn't found a method to change the resolution, nevertheless I can get it. So I got the screen width/height, the window width/height and 4 coordinates in 1024x768 for a rectangle. What should I do?

Comment: First of all, OpenGL does not control the resolution of the screen. You have to use something like WGL, GLX, CGL, EGL, etc. which handle the platform-specific details for that. Most people do not bother interfacing with those APIs directly and use something like GLUT, GLFW, SDL, etc. instead to make code more portable. As for the rest of your question, you probably want object-space coordinates and window-space coordinates to match for this, so you should consider a viewport and *orthographic* projection matrix that have the same dimensions as your window and an identity modelview matrix.

Comment: My ortho `glOrtho(0, scrw, scrh, 0, -100, 100);` and my perspective `gluPerspective(40, scrw/scrh, 0.1, 2000);` matrix where scrw is the `GlutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH)` and similarly the scrh. As it revealed therefore I note I use Glut.

Comment: You only need one of those two calls. They multiply and store the ***current*** matrix, so if you call both of those you will produce a projection matrix that is completely meaningless.

Comment: I also have to render in 2D and 3D. The menu in 2D, and the background thingies in 3D.